# Connected device (the doctor check crashed)

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, adb

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3296],
    locale id-ID)
    • Flutter version 3.19.3 on channel stable at D:\Android\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ba39319843 (3 weeks ago), 2024-03-07 15:22:21 -0600
    • Engine revision 2e4ba9c6fb
    • Dart version 3.3.1
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\awnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0--11185874)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0--11185874)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\awnan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.84.0

[☠] Connected device (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is
      not helpful, please let us know about this issue at
      https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ Error: Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_HOME
      environment variable:
      C:\Users\awnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
    • #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
      #1      AndroidDevices.pollingGetDevices
      (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device_discovery.dart:75:7)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #2      PollingDeviceDiscovery._populateDevices
      (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:549:36)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #3      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:518:21)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #4      DeviceManager.refreshAllDevices
      (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:216:40)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #5      DeviceValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:739:34)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #6      Future.any.onValue (dart:async/future.dart:608:5)
      <asynchronous suspension>


[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

i try to found but still not working

Comment: Does this file 'C:\Users\awnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'  exist in your system?

Comment: What happens if you manually execute `C:\Users\awnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices` ?